# How to call the stuffs you usually do (in bathroom) after get up at the morning?

Tags: daily-life

After getup, I usually washing my face, brush my teeth, take a shower, hand washing, and do something just to clear my body. Is there a word or phrase in Japanese that describle all thing we do in the bathroom at the morning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first phrase that comes to mind is:

> 「朝{あさ}の身支度{みじたく}」 or 「毎朝{まいあさ}の身支度」

What that consists of will differ from person to person and a shower may or may not be included because more people in Japan bathe or shower in the evening than in the morning.

In any case, if you used one of those phrases, every Japanese-speaker would know what you are talking about.